# Show all the values for the X-axis in SSRS

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a chart in an SSRS report. I usually have 10 different values for the X axis. For some reason, it only shows some of them when the chart is rendered. It renders fine if I use less different values.

Example:

```
5      X                X       
4             X                X
3         X                  
2  X             X          X      X  X
1  
  2000   2002   2004   2006   2008  2010
```

Values for the years `2001,2003,2005,2007 and 2009` are hidden.

Is there a setting to tell it to show all the different values available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have used in the past is to set the `LabelInterval` to 1 rather than auto.